# How to run a tracetcp in C# and get the output result?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

Below is the my code. 
Is there someting wrong or missing in my code?

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    string strCmdText = string.Empty;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "tracetcp vrtpmkap2001:445";
    p.Start();
    string q = string.Empty;
    while (!p.HasExited)
    {
        q += p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    string r = q.ToString();
}
```

I can't get the output of the tracetcp.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

```
string cmd = "/c tracetcp vrtpmkap2001:445" ; 
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd; 
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
proc.Start();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

I already figure out the problem.
when c# run a cmd.exe it uses SysWOW64 cmd.exe

i just add the tracetcp.exe in SysWOW64 folder.